# Java calendar get the current date, without hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds, in milliseconds

Tags: java, calendar

I would like to get the current date in milliseconds with only year, month and date. But when I use this code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear(Calendar.HOUR);
cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
currentDate = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

I still get the time in milliseconds with the hour. 
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
currentDate = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Be carefull on the timezone of your Calendar.

Comment: on Android it gave me yesterday (midnight)

Comment: Did you take care of your timezone @Anthony?

Comment: Note `.reset()` and `.set(0)` works differently. When using `reset()` you must reset both `HOUR_OF_DAY` and `HOUR` to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 9):

If you only want this relative to GMT and explicitly just want milliseconds, you can use this:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long today = now - now % 86400000;
```

Answer (score 5):

from the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#clear%28int%29):
The HOUR_OF_DAY, HOUR and AM_PM fields are handled independently and the the resolution rule for the time of day is applied. Clearing one of the fields doesn't reset the hour of day value of this Calendar. Use set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0) to reset the hour value.

```
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

might need to set AM/PM as well

Comment: Am/PM - that's why you use Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY as the other example does

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now()
```

## `LocalDate`

If what you want is actually just the date without the time, use `LocalDate` class.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you want a date with the time-of-day set to the first moment of the day, ask java.time to determine that moment for you. Do not assume the first moment is at 00:00:00. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time means first moment may occur at some other time such as 01:00:00.

Use that time zone object, the `ZoneId`, to generate a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = today.atStartOfDay( z );  // Determine the first moment of the day on this date for this time zone.
```

To view this same moment as a value in UTC, extract a `Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Avoid the troublesome old date-time classes such as `Calendar`. These are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/):

```
   long millis = new DateMidnight().getMillis();
```