# setSeries paint by index always results in the same color

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using JFreeChart to render a candlestick chart with multiple datasets. Specifically I am trying to have a color variation on the smaDataset thats using a XYLineandShapeRenderer. After adding the sma100 and 200 series to the dataset and applying the renderer to it, I get no effect and the lines are both blue no matter what I do.

```
 CandlestickRenderer renderer = new CandlestickRenderer();
    renderer.setAutoWidthMethod(CandlestickRenderer.WIDTHMETHOD_SMALLEST);
    DateAxis xAxis = new DateAxis("Time");
    XYPlot pricePlot = new XYPlot(ohlcDataset, xAxis, new NumberAxis("Price"), renderer);

    //DEBUG
    pricePlot.setDataset(1, createSMADataset(this.series, 100));
    pricePlot.setDataset(2, createSMADataset(this.series, 200));
    pricePlot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(1, 0);
    pricePlot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(2, 0);

    XYLineAndShapeRenderer smaRenderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true, false);
    smaRenderer.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.BLUE);
    smaRenderer.setSeriesPaint(2, Color.RED);
    pricePlot.setRenderer(1, smaRenderer);
    pricePlot.setRenderer(2, smaRenderer);

    pricePlot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.WHITE);
    pricePlot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(false);
    pricePlot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(false);

    NumberAxis numberAxis = (NumberAxis) pricePlot.getRangeAxis();
    pricePlot.setDatasetRenderingOrder(DatasetRenderingOrder.FORWARD);
    pricePlot.setRangeAxisLocation(AxisLocation.TOP_OR_RIGHT);
    numberAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);

    // combinedPlot
    CombinedDomainXYPlot combinedPlot = new CombinedDomainXYPlot(xAxis); // DateAxis
    combinedPlot.setGap(10.0);
    combinedPlot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.VERTICAL);
    //add plots to combined plot
    combinedPlot.add(pricePlot, 80);
    combinedPlot.add(getRSIPlot(), 20);
```

Comment: This complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55584636/230513) may be relevant; more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28519356/230513).

Comment: Also consider a custom `DrawingSupplier`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40545725/230513).